# unencrypt 7zip files in ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, encryption, 7-zip

I have an encrypted 7zip file, but i cannot open it, it appears that p7zip does not support encryption yet.  Do you know a program that can open it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

p7zip does support encryption - see the documentation at /usr/share/doc/p7zip-full/DOCS/MANUAL/switches/method.htm

Here's the syntax to encrypt a file.

```
7z a -psecret -mx=9 -mm=Deflate -mem=AES256 -tzip inputfile.7z inputfile
```

The command line syntax is overly complex, but it works.

Comment: Actually I just installed 7z from get-apt - i was using p7zip ealier and now archive manager can unzip & unencrypt the files so I guess i'm taking care of.